# Damaged queues in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I usually see damaged queues in  our activemq5.4.2 ,meaning queue's are malformed and i had to  remove the kahaDB files and bounce the broker to resolve this. all messages stored in queue are lost during. How to prevent this damaged queues without loss of data ?

Below are the logs of broker,
ERROR | Failed to reset batching | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore | ActiveMQ Broker[AMQBROKER-TEST] Scheduler
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PageFile is not loaded
        at org.apache.kahadb.page.PageFile.assertLoaded(PageFile.java:715)
        at org.apache.kahadb.page.PageFile.tx(PageFile.java:239)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore$KahaDBMessageStore.resetBatching(KahaDBStore.java:510)
        at org.apache.activemq.store.ProxyMessageStore.resetBatching(ProxyMessageStore.java:93)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch.resetBatch(QueueStorePrefetch.java:85)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.fillBatch(AbstractStoreCursor.java:254)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor.reset(AbstractStoreCursor.java:108)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.StoreQueueCursor.reset(StoreQueueCursor.java:157)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.doBrowse(Queue.java:1026)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.expireMessages(Queue.java:783)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.access$100(Queue.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$2.run(Queue.java:123)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
INFO  | Transport failed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | Async Exception Handler

WARN | Failed to register MBean: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=AMQBROKER-TEST,Type=Queue,Destination=_ onEvent&X171249188Y1Z
 INFO | Transport failed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
 INFO | Transport failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 INFO | Transport failed: java.io.EOFException

Comment: Can you add some more details about how the queue is 'damaged'? What happens when you send and receive messages from these queues?

Comment: Once the queue are damage all applications are not able to send/receive messages and it is throwing specified bean not found errors.

Comment: Can you post the stack traces for the errors and any relevant part of the amq broker log? The broker must be hitting some problem, maybe with the storage.

Comment: Hi..I have posted the broker logs.